# Topdown 2d movement script not working relating to rb2D.position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My topdown 2d movement script isn't working (ie when I input a horizontal input the player character does not move) & I really have no I idea why (although I'm sure the solution is simple; I'm still new to C# & unity)
I've attached the player movement script to a game object with a:

- Transform
- Sprite Renderer
- RigidBody2D (Dynamic & simulated = false)
  [RigidBody2D Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIn7M.png)

The Code:

```
// This is attached within Unity (I know I can do it in the code; the only reason I don't is so that I can confirm it is the correct RigidBody2D attached to the script)
public Rigidbody2D rb2D;
// Serialize Field so I can set the float size within unity for debugging
[SerializeField] float moveSpeed;

private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb2D.position += new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"),Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")).normalized * moveSpeed;
    }
```

I haven't been usy unity for too long so it could be a problem in the editor; because I've used code similar to this before & it has worked.

I am also aware that there are multiple ways to move a character in a scene; [source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tNtOcDryKv4). I have chosen the Rigidbody position method because it will allow me in the future to add collisions to my game if I want (without ruining the movement).

Well anyhow I thought I'd post the question here to see if anyone could help.
Thanks :)

Comment: Can you give a screenshot of your rigidbody settings? @ZapperPaddy

Comment: Could you define a bit clearer what exactly `My topdown 2d movement script isn't working` means?

Comment: yep can do @Obscure021 sorry for the delay (I half expected it to take longer for people to respond)

Comment: @derHugo when I press start unity my character does not move in any direction (when I press the movement keys); even though I am adding a new vector to his rb2d. I've tested with debug.log(inputHorizontal) where inputHorizontal is input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") & it shows up as 1 & -1 as it should so I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: sure the `moveSpeed` isn't maybe `0`?

Comment: in general afaik you should leave `simulated` enabled but rather set `isKinematic` to `true`

Comment: @derHugo Yeah its set to 500 so it shouldn't be a problem, & I just changed the Rigidbody to Kinematic (thanks for the tip) & still no luck, is very strange.

Comment: @derHugo hold on it turns out I was setting simulated to true & false in other parts of my code & when I commented that out it worked! YAY :) just another side question on the note of that if I want to turn on gravity again do I just set isDynamic to true?

Comment: If you only want to turn of gravity but otherwise handle physics you rather want to set `gravityScale` to `0` ...

Comment: Sweet, well thanks for all the tips @derHugo twas very helpful :) & is now working flawlessly!